# how to write browser specific css properties?

Tags: .net, html, css

Please guide me how to write browser specific css properties (not classes or ids) ? I can't manage different css files for different browsers. I want to use same css file and classes but in case of differences I will mention browser pacific properties.

Please guide me how to do that.

Comment: Sounds like you want vendor specific prefixes (eg `-webkit`, `-moz`), but those only work on certain properties. Regardless you will be writing separate code for different browsers. Why _not_ use different CSS files or apply a browser specific tag to the body of your html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery to apply different css classes

```
if($.browser.msie){
$("#someDiv").addclass("SomeClass");
}
```

$.browser.msie is for Internet Explorer
$.browser.chrome for chrome
$.browser.mozilla for mozilla
$.browser.safari for safari
$.browser.opera for opera

This way would give you flexibility when it comes to problems based on positioning

reference : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Answer (score 3):

Please be more specific, but when you're generally writing css you want it compatible with all browsers.

Things like webkit vary, (in firefox it's moz) but usually if you look up certain things in css there's a way to do it in every browser.

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #cccccc, #333333, #cccccc);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #cccccc, #333333, #cccccc);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #cccccc, #333333, #cccccc);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #cccccc, #333333, #cccccc);
```

For example, the above code should work in most modern browsers, and if all of them fail then just have a fallback (plain black for this example).

Also, you can always just use different css files, it's not very difficult.

Comment: yentup please guide how to write for IE6 or IE7 ? What about Safari ?

Comment: Safari uses `webkit` like Chrome, and you have to look up the compatibilities for IE, but you can do things like:

    `<!--[if IE 8]>
    <style></style>
    <![endif]-->`

Answer (score 1):

Very simply, you either have to write out each vendor prefix as needed OR use a CSS preprocessor such as LESS.

Prefixr also works as a plugin for Sublime Text, if you happen to be using it (which I do except I use LESS).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean **Vendor Specific Prefixes**. I've found something interesting you might like:
http://css3please.com/.

Check this out for other related tools: http://css-tricks.com/tldr-on-vendor-prefix-drama/

Answer (score 0):

If I may could I recommend a different approach.  Instead of writing for each browser could you test for the feature and then modify your code according to that?  If so this project will be helpful:

http://modernizr.com/

Comment: again after testing I will need to fix the code. For this I will need to know how to write broswer spacific CSS :)